# Report returning multiple values per unique id when field has two values per uniqe

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report in Jaspersoft iReport that is returning multiple lines when a unique id has multiple values in another field.

**Example Output**

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   B
3   A
3   B
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   B
3   A, B
```

**Relevant XML**

*Field Name*

```
<field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Value" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

*Text Element*

```
<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>

<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>       
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Value}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Please explain the structure of your data. At first glance your *unique id* does not seem to be *unique* in your data set.

Comment: ID is meant to only show once per line, and if there is multiple values in the value column i want them to be concatenated into one seperated by a comma

Comment: I'd try that using sub data sources, the main query returning IDs uniquely and the sub query returning the values for the respective ID. JasperReports is not my specialty, though. Thus, I'd not be surprised if there was a neater solution.

Comment: Would it be possible to put some sort of case when logic in the Value field to say when count of value >= 2 then concat results?

Comment: Unless you provide more details on the kind of your data (SQL query? XML? Beans? Something else?) and your report (the relevant parts of your jrxml, query and report elements of your list), one can hardly provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Hello,it is built in in ireport, the backend of the report is XML.
The backend of the database is SQL, the fields are currently just $F{ID} & $F{Value}

Comment: ... **and your report (the relevant parts of your jrxml, query and report elements of your list)**, please.

Comment: sorry, im not entirely sure what more i need to provide in regards to the previous comment.

Comment: When you generate a report, be it manually or using iReport, you create a XML file describing the report. This XML file has the extension jrxml. From this file please supply the the relevant parts, the query and the report elements of your list.

Comment: Ah ok, i understand :) i will get the relevant XML now and update the question.

Comment: Added XML to question

Comment: the query itself is still missing, in case of XML data sources probably a XPath.

Comment: There is no query, its just pulling the data directly from the source, with the two fields

Comment: Can i not just change the field for Value from `$F{Value}` to something like `SELECT $F{Value} WHERE $F{ID} == $F{ID}`

Comment: As you have a XML datasource, SQL selects won't help much. Here you more often can work with XPath expressions. I have fooled around with them and sub datasources a bit now, but I always had an initial XPath for my datasource and I don't know what elements JasperReport looks at by default. Could you provide the base XML (or some representative excerpt of it? This could help creating the appropriate XPaths etc..

Comment: Whats the xpath expression for a "where in" query

Comment: Something like $X{IN, Value, $F{ID}}

Comment: Could you provide the base XML (or some representative excerpt of it)? This could help creating the appropriate XPaths etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.... For future use..

Added everything into an "ID" Group Header 1 then left the Value in the Detail 1 and gave the required result.

**Output**

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   B
3   A, B
```

Comment: I didn't use code as far as I can remember. Like I said drag the id into the header and the value into the detail

Comment: Right, can you the final Relevant XML? I have a problem like this and it really helps to see the final code.

Comment: i didnt change the XML, it was all done in the front end of ireports