# $F{FIELD} Jaspersoft iReport Return one value only

Tags: jasper-reports

When using $F{FIELD} in Jaspersoft iReport, i want to return one value only (the first value).

Whether this is used in the 'Print when expression' or in the 'Text field expression' i don't know.

**Current Output**

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   A
    B
    C
5   A
    B
6   A
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   A
5   A
6   A
```

Comment: What is the essential difference to the situation [in your former question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25642245/1729265)?

Comment: This one is selecting the top "Value" per "ID" the other is selecting all "Value"s per "ID" but showing them on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have placed your filed in detail band of the report then select the field and add the Print when Expression property to

```
          Print when Expression property -    $V{REPORT_COUNT} ==1
```

Comment: This is now making the values blank rather than just showing the top value

Comment: Can you post your query ? , I think it can be easily done by query.